# Android studio Build failed with NDK

Tags: java, android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

found error while build the project with NDK

error

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmxecg.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#automatic_packaging_of_prebuilt_dependencies_used_by_cmake

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion config.compileSdk

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion config.minSdk
    targetSdkVersion config.targetSdk
    versionCode config.versionCode
    versionName config.versionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/libmxecg/lib']

    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

}

[image]

In another module i also use Cmake and it works fine when i add another module with Cmake it shows error.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62088079/error-when-building-project-with-ndk-support-after-updating-to-android-studio-4 ?

Comment: yes but the same project where i import these modules working fine

Comment: I had such issue when project is built on AS 4.0 but on AS 3.6 it works fine.

Comment: @NikolayKhilyuk when i comment these lines of cmake it build successfully but i need cmake
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}

Comment: Did you try packagingOptions {pickFirst '**/libmxecg.so'} instead of jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/libmxecg/lib'] ?

Comment: yes it run now when i use 4.0.0 gradle and also project run 
packagingOptions {pickFirst '**/libmxecg.so'} with this

Comment: Thanks what does it mean?
packagingOptions {pickFirst '**/libmxecg.so'}
@NikolayKhilyuk

Comment: It's new approach for native libraries packaging into APK.